# Android SDK problem setting ringtone

Tags: android, sdk, ringtone

I am trying to add and set the default ringtone on the emulator/phone. The ringtone has been downloaded and is stored in the application folder /dada/dada/com.xxx/ringtones. the ringtones are ogg files.

I use the following code to add and set the ringtone:

```
public void setRingtone() {
    aajoAsset asset = null;
    asset = mXXXX.getAssetManager().getCurrentRingtoneAsset();

    if (asset != null && asset.isSaved()/* && !asset.getName().equals(mLastAssetName)*/) {
        String filepath = asset.getDirectoryPath() + asset.getFilename();
        File ringtoneFile = new File(filepath);

        if (LOG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Sending Intent : " + Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        }

        mContext.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://" + asset.getDirectoryPath() + asset.getFilename())));  

        ContentValues content = new ContentValues();
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "1234");
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, asset.getSize());
        content.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "1234");
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION, 4800);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
        content.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        if (LOG) {
            Log.i(TAG, "the absolute path of the file is : " + ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(
        ringtoneFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = mContext.getContentResolver().insert(uri, content);

        if (LOG) {
            Log.i(TAG,"the ringtone uri is : " + newUri);
        }


        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(mContext, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

        mLastAssetName = asset.getName();
    }
```

The code executes fine and the ringtone shows in the ringtone list but when I click on it to test it or when I simulate a incoming call I get the following errors in LogCat:

```
DEBUG/MediaPlayer(1230): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
ERROR/MediaPlayerService(33): Couldn't open fd for content://media/internal/audio/media/1
ERROR/MediaPlayer(1230): Unable to to create media player
ERROR/RingtoneManager(1230): Failed to open ringtone content://media/internal/audio/media/1
```

I have searched for solutions in many forums and cannot find any.

any help is most welcome

Thanks

Comment: I didn't know android supported Ogg ringtones

Comment: I have this problem when trying to use a ringtone I put in the alarms directrory on the sdcard. The ringtone appears on the list but no sound plays.